# How to convert Alphanumeric field to Upper case in salesforce using Validation

Tags: salesforce, admin, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

How to Convert Lower Case Alphanumeric field Value to Upper Case Alphanumeric field value in salesforce

Ex:  abc35687657896 --> ABC35687657896

Answer (score 0):

Formula field.

```
 UPPER(text)
```

Can use that formula in a trigger flow or something and paste where you want.

[image]